# JBoss WildFly HTTP Management API Usage

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am trying to fetch information in WildFly10 using its HTTP Management API.

I want to perform following operations :

1. Find status of server
   `http://localhost:9990/management?operation=attribute&name=server-state
   Output : "running"`
2. Find status of a deployed application
   `http://localhost:9990/management/deployment/test.war?operation=attribute&name=status
   Output : "OK"`
3. Deploy/Undeploy/Redeploy an application.
4. Start/Shutdown/Restart the server.

I have the URL for first two (where attribute is used) , but I am unable to find correct URL for the last two (where operation is used).

I can see the operations listed in another tab beside attributes in the UI. It may be similar, but I could not figure out the correct usage.

Any help/direction?

Comment: Is there any specific requirement, you need this info via URL ? You can try CLI commands for same.

Comment: No such specific requirement. And I am also thinking of using CLI.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the server state for 3. thus those are POST and not GET methods.
Please take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/The+HTTP+management+API

Comment: I have gone through the docs.
Do you mean to say that it is not possible to achieve 3 and 4?
Looking at their Management Model, redeploy/undeploy operations do not require any input. So it should be possible via simple URLs.

Comment: It changes the 'enabled' attribute so it is a POST :) GET should be idempotent : aka shouldn't change the state of the server.